# Unknown provider: $cordovaContactsProvider <- $cordovaContacts

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am using ionic framework 1.3 and trying to read phone contacts using:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-contacts
```

And

```
.controller('TestControlsCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, $cordovaContacts) {
    $scope.selectContacts = function() {
      $cordovaContacts.find().then(function(allContacts) { 
        $scope.contacts = allContacts;
      });
    };
});
```

But I am getting this error

> 09-26 19:07:25.539 E/Web Console( 4188): Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $cordovaContactsProvider <- $cordovaContacts <- TestControlsCtrl
>
> 09-26 19:07:25.539 E/Web Console( 4188): http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/$injector/unpr?p0=%24cordovaContactsProvider%20%3C-%20%24cordovaContacts%20%3C-%20TestControlsCtrl
>
> 09-26 19:07:25.539 E/Web Console( 4188):     at file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13438:12
>
> 09-26 19:07:25.539 E/Web Console( 4188):     at file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17788:19
>
> 09-26 19:07:25.539 E/Web Console( 4188):     at Object.getService [as get] (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17941:39)
>
> 09-26 19:07:25.539 E/Web Console( 4188):     at file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17793:45
>
> 09-26 19:07:25.539 E/Web Console( 4188):     at getService (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17941:39)
>
> 09-26 19:07:25.539 E/Web Console( 4188):     at injectionArgs (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17965:58)
>
> 09-26 19:07:25.539 E/Web Console( 4188):     at Object.instantiate (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:18007:18)
>
> 09-26 19:07:25.539 E/Web Console( 4188):     at $controller (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:23412:28)
>
> 09-26 19:07:25.539 E/Web Console( 4188):     at [object Object].appendViewElement (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:59900:24)
>
> 09-26 19:07:25.539 E/Web Console( 4188):     at Object.render (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:57893:41) at file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:26794

NPM verion 3.8.6
Node version 5.11.0

What am I doing wrong? Please help

Comment: Is this web console error ?

Comment: http://ngcordova.com/docs/common-issues/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added this plugin Cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-contacts

controller:

```
    $scope.allContacts= [];
   function findContacts() {
    var options = new ContactFindOptions();
    options.filter = "";
    options.multiple = true;

    fields = ["displayName"];
    navigator.contacts.find(fields, contactfindSuccess, contactfindError, options);

    function contactfindSuccess(contacts) {
       for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
         alert("Display Name = " + contacts[i].displayName);
         $scope.allContacts.push(contacts[i]);
      }
    }

   function contactfindError(message) {
      alert('Failed because: ' + message);
   }

}
```